# STM32F4 DMA doesn't control ADC channels

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

I'm trying to set up my STM32F407-Discovery board to read multiple ADC channels from ADC1 using the DMA controller. I can easily read the analog value one at a time without using DMA, but as soon as I enable DMA for the ADC, `ADC1->DR` is always 0, and `adc_vals` is filled with zeros. Furthermore, it hangs on `while(!ADC_GetFlagStatus(ADC1, ADC_FLAG_EOC));`.

EDIT: it would appear `DMA_GetCmdStatus` is returning DISABLED.  Any ideas?

Is there a way to start the ADC or something that I'm missing?

```c
//setup adc1: in1,2,3,8,9,15
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_ADC1,ENABLE); //adc1 on the apb2 peripheral bus
ADC_InitTypeDef adc;
ADC_DeInit(); //set adc to default state
adc.ADC_DataAlign = ADC_DataAlign_Right;
adc.ADC_Resolution = ADC_Resolution_12b;//12 bit = 4096
adc.ADC_ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
adc.ADC_ExternalTrigConv = ADC_ExternalTrigConv_T1_CC1;
adc.ADC_ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_ExternalTrigConvEdge_None;
adc.ADC_NbrOfConversion = NUM_ADC;
adc.ADC_ScanConvMode = ENABLE;
ADC_Init(ADC1,&adc);


ADC_DMACmd(ADC1, ENABLE); //enable adc for dma.  When this line is removed, I see data on ADC1->DR


ADC_Cmd(ADC1,ENABLE);

ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1,ADC_Channel_1,1,ADC_SampleTime_144Cycles);//1:1710, 0
//ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1,ADC_Channel_2,2,ADC_SampleTime_144Cycles);//2:1710, 0
//ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1,ADC_Channel_3,3,ADC_SampleTime_144Cycles);//3:1710, 0
ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1,ADC_Channel_8,4,ADC_SampleTime_144Cycles);//8:3520
ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1,ADC_Channel_9,5,ADC_SampleTime_144Cycles);//9:1000
//ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1,ADC_Channel_15,6,ADC_SampleTime_144Cycles);//15:3920


//DMA for multiple adc channels:
RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_DMA1, ENABLE); //dma1 clock enable
DMA_InitTypeDef dma;

DMA_DeInit(DMA2_Stream0); //reset DMA2 stream 0 to default values
dma.DMA_Channel = DMA_Channel_0;
dma.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t)&(ADC1->DR);
dma.DMA_Memory0BaseAddr = (uint32_t)&adc_vals[0];
dma.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralToMemory;
dma.DMA_BufferSize = NUM_ADC;
dma.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
dma.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
dma.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_HalfWord;
dma.DMA_MemoryDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_HalfWord;
dma.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Circular;
dma.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_High;
dma.DMA_FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMode_Disable;
dma.DMA_FIFOThreshold = DMA_FIFOThreshold_HalfFull;
dma.DMA_MemoryBurst = DMA_MemoryBurst_Single;
dma.DMA_PeripheralBurst = DMA_PeripheralBurst_Single;
DMA_Init(DMA2_Stream0, &dma);

DMA_ITConfig(DMA2_Stream0, DMA_IT_TC | DMA_IT_HT, ENABLE); //Enable DMA Stream Half / Transfer Complete interrupt

DMA_Cmd(DMA2_Stream0, ENABLE); //DMA2_Stream0 enable

//dma transfer complete interrupt:
NVIC_InitTypeDef nvic;
//Enable DMA1 channel IRQ Channel
nvic.NVIC_IRQChannel = DMA2_Stream0_IRQn;
nvic.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0;
nvic.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;
nvic.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
NVIC_Init(&nvic);

ADC_SoftwareStartConv(ADC1);//Start the adc conversion
```

Comment: Well, part of my problem was that dma wasn't set up before the adc.  Now, I can read exactly one adc value from ADC1->DR, but it freezes there and is still zero in adc_vals[i]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least you can try:

- change `DMA_PeripheralInc` to enable
- use `ADC_DMARequestAfterLastTransferCmd(ADC, Enable);` for dma request after group conversion.
- init `ADC_CommonInitTypeDef`
- init GPIO, if not

Moreover enabling ADC before all the configurations is strange.

In my opinion the best way is to copy-paste "ADC_DualModeRegulSimu"example from standard peripherals library. It contains beautiful code exactly for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There were a number of errors.  Here's my working code for anybody else having the same trouble:

```
    //DMA for multiple adc channels:
RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_DMA2, ENABLE);
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_ADC1, ENABLE); //ADC1 on APB2 peripheral bus

DMA_InitTypeDef dma; //dma2/stream0/channel0
dma.DMA_Channel = DMA_Channel_0; 
dma.DMA_Memory0BaseAddr = (uint32_t)&adcVal;
dma.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t)&(ADC1->DR);
dma.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralToMemory;
dma.DMA_BufferSize = 6;
dma.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
dma.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
dma.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_HalfWord;
dma.DMA_MemoryDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_HalfWord;
dma.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Circular;
dma.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_High;
dma.DMA_FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMode_Enable;              
dma.DMA_FIFOThreshold = DMA_FIFOThreshold_HalfFull;
dma.DMA_MemoryBurst = DMA_MemoryBurst_Single;
dma.DMA_PeripheralBurst = DMA_PeripheralBurst_Single;
DMA_Init(DMA2_Stream0, &dma);
DMA_Cmd(DMA2_Stream0, ENABLE); //dMA2_Stream0 enable

//analog inputs: PA1,2,3, PC5, PB0,1
gpio.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_1 | GPIO_Pin_2 | GPIO_Pin_3;
gpio.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AN;
gpio.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &gpio);
gpio.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_5;
GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &gpio);
gpio.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0 | GPIO_Pin_1;
GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &gpio);

//ADC common init
ADC_CommonInitTypeDef adcCommon;
adcCommon.ADC_Mode = ADC_Mode_Independent;
adcCommon.ADC_Prescaler = ADC_Prescaler_Div2;
adcCommon.ADC_DMAAccessMode = ADC_DMAAccessMode_Disabled;
adcCommon.ADC_TwoSamplingDelay = ADC_TwoSamplingDelay_5Cycles;
ADC_CommonInit(&adcCommon);

//setup adc1: in1,2,3,8,9,15
ADC_InitTypeDef adc;
ADC_DeInit(); //set adc to default state
adc.ADC_DataAlign = ADC_DataAlign_Right; //mask 0b 00001111 11111111
adc.ADC_Resolution = ADC_Resolution_12b;//12 bit = 4096
adc.ADC_ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE; //continuous: constantly converting data - can always read register
adc.ADC_ExternalTrigConv = ADC_ExternalTrigConv_T1_CC1;//external trigger conversion (?)
adc.ADC_ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_ExternalTrigConvEdge_None;
adc.ADC_NbrOfConversion = 6;
adc.ADC_ScanConvMode = ENABLE;//single/multichannel
ADC_Init(ADC1,&adc);

ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1,ADC_Channel_1,1,ADC_SampleTime_56Cycles); ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1,ADC_Channel_2,2,ADC_SampleTime_56Cycles);
ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1,ADC_Channel_3,3,ADC_SampleTime_56Cycles);
ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1,ADC_Channel_8,4,ADC_SampleTime_56Cycles);
ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1,ADC_Channel_9,5,ADC_SampleTime_56Cycles);
ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1,ADC_Channel_15,6,ADC_SampleTime_56Cycles);


ADC_DMARequestAfterLastTransferCmd(ADC1, ENABLE); //single adc repeated

ADC_DMACmd(ADC1, ENABLE);
ADC_Cmd(ADC1,ENABLE);
```

Comment: the main problem you have is HAL. Bare register is easy and straightforward. I would like to see more complicated configurations :). HAL - months of work - registers - hours.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the code ethan, made minor mod to fit my case and to work as a general function.

```
volatile uint16_t adcVal[6];

void Setup_DMA_ADC( void )
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef gpio;
    //DMA for multiple adc channels:
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_DMA2, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_ADC1, ENABLE); //ADC1 on APB2 peripheral bus
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOC, ENABLE);

    DMA_InitTypeDef dma; //dma2/stream0/channel0
    dma.DMA_Channel = DMA_Channel_0;
    dma.DMA_Memory0BaseAddr = (uint32_t) &adcVal[0];
    dma.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t)&(ADC1->DR);
    dma.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralToMemory;
    dma.DMA_BufferSize = 6;
    dma.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
    dma.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
    dma.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_HalfWord;
    dma.DMA_MemoryDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_HalfWord;
    dma.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Circular;
    dma.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_High;
    dma.DMA_FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMode_Enable;
    dma.DMA_FIFOThreshold = DMA_FIFOThreshold_HalfFull;
    dma.DMA_MemoryBurst = DMA_MemoryBurst_Single;
    dma.DMA_PeripheralBurst = DMA_PeripheralBurst_Single;
    DMA_Init(DMA2_Stream0, &dma);
    DMA_Cmd(DMA2_Stream0, ENABLE); //dMA2_Stream0 enable

    //analog inputs: PA1,2,3, PC5, PB0,1
    GPIO_StructInit(&gpio);
    gpio.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_1 | GPIO_Pin_2 | GPIO_Pin_3;
    gpio.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AN;
    gpio.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &gpio);
    gpio.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_5;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &gpio);
    gpio.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0 | GPIO_Pin_1;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &gpio);

    //ADC common init
    ADC_CommonInitTypeDef adcCommon;
    adcCommon.ADC_Mode = ADC_Mode_Independent;
    adcCommon.ADC_Prescaler = ADC_Prescaler_Div2;
    adcCommon.ADC_DMAAccessMode = ADC_DMAAccessMode_Disabled;
    adcCommon.ADC_TwoSamplingDelay = ADC_TwoSamplingDelay_5Cycles;
    ADC_CommonInit(&adcCommon);

    //setup adc1: in1,2,3,8,9,15
    ADC_InitTypeDef adc;
    ADC_DeInit(); //set adc to default state
    adc.ADC_DataAlign = ADC_DataAlign_Right; //mask 0b 00001111 11111111
    adc.ADC_Resolution = ADC_Resolution_12b;//12 bit = 4096
    adc.ADC_ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE; //continuous: constantly converting data - can always read register
    adc.ADC_ExternalTrigConv = DISABLE;//ADC_ExternalTrigConv_T1_CC1;//external trigger conversion (?)
    adc.ADC_ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_ExternalTrigConvEdge_None;
    adc.ADC_NbrOfConversion = 6;
    adc.ADC_ScanConvMode = ENABLE;//single/multichannel
    ADC_Init(ADC1,&adc);

    ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1,ADC_Channel_1,1,ADC_SampleTime_56Cycles);
    ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1,ADC_Channel_2,2,ADC_SampleTime_56Cycles);
    ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1,ADC_Channel_3,3,ADC_SampleTime_56Cycles);
    ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1,ADC_Channel_8,4,ADC_SampleTime_56Cycles);
    ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1,ADC_Channel_9,5,ADC_SampleTime_56Cycles);
    ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1,ADC_Channel_15,6,ADC_SampleTime_56Cycles);


    ADC_DMARequestAfterLastTransferCmd(ADC1, ENABLE); //single adc repeated

    ADC_DMACmd(ADC1, ENABLE);
    ADC_Cmd(ADC1,ENABLE);
    // Start ADC conversion
    ADC_SoftwareStartConv(ADC1);
    return;
}
```